# how to check whether Linux is going down for halt or reboot

Tags: linux, init

I need to execute some command when system is going down for halt/poweroff.

I need to know this inside my script `/etc/init.d/myScript` which is called when system is going down.

I used to do it by checking `$runlevel` variable and if it is set to 0, then system was going down for halt, it was working for instance in Raspbian a few years ago.

However, in my Linux cubieboard2 4.9.12-sunxi Armbian this variable is not set, and when I execute `runlevel` command inside "STOP" case in myScript it says it is in N 5 runlevel which is not true because I have executed poweroff

All tips are welcome.

Comment: I would think of two ways: (a) using the `last` command, which can give you the last shutdown or the last reboot time depending on the options, or (b) parsing the `/var/log/messages` file. Does any of these work?

Comment: Isn't halting the system done by switching to runlevel 0 and thus executing all the scripts in `/etc/rc0.d/` directory?  So, even if you cannot recognize the current runlevel via `$runlevel` (which should be `$RUNLEVEL` btw., according to my manpage) or the `runlevel` command, you can place a symlink in `/etc/rc0.d/` to a special script which only gets called when the system is halted.

Comment: If you are running systemd you can try getting the runlevel through "systemctl get-default"

Comment: What does `chkconfig` shows about your services. You might like to read LSB chapter 20 https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Handling `runlevel` in script will not be needed if you are adhering to LSB standard.
As per LSB spec, you might like to header to your script. Following is a example
header.

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

More details at chapter 20 of [LSB standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic.pdf)

Additionally, you can control `runlevel` at which your script will invoked.It can also be controlled by `chkconfig` command